# How to detect Materialized.js modal closing event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, modal-dialog, materialized

How to detect the closing event for `materialized.js`?

I want to run some JavaScript code when the modal got closed either by clicking on modal close button or pressing escape button or clicking on any other area of the screen.

Comment: I don't know a framework/library called materialized.js. Do you mean this library? http://materializecss.com/modals.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like you mean closing event for *modal* of the **materializecss** framework.

As for 0.97.1 version (15th of September, 2015) When opening a modal, you can pass options (see: http://materializecss.com/modals.html#options), but note, that it's a very  delusive description, as the options are not being saved when using `lean_modal` (https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/1464), so they should be passed only to openModal.

To sum up:

```
var onModalHide = function() {
    alert("Modal closed!");
};

$("#id-of-your-modal").openModal({
    complete : onModalHide
});
```

Answer (score 11):

It' easy now with the latest version:

http://materializecss.com/modals.html

You can customize the behavior of each modal using these options. For example, you can call a custom function to run when a modal is dismissed. To do this, just place your function in the intialization code as shown below.

```
  $('.modal').modal({
      dismissible: true, // Modal can be dismissed by clicking outside of the modal
      ready: function(modal, trigger) { // Callback for Modal open. Modal and trigger parameters available.
        alert("Ready");
        console.log(modal, trigger);
      },
      complete: function() { alert('Closed'); } // Callback for Modal close
    }
  );
```

EDIT: Originally I have answered it long time back but recently [@JackRogers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7594368/jack-rogers) reviewed and here is the code please use it if it works :) I have no work setup to test it.

```
$('.modal').modal({
      dismissible: true, // Modal can be dismissed by clicking outside of the modal
      onOpenEnd: function(modal, trigger) { // Callback for Modal open. Modal and trigger parameters available.
        alert("Ready");
        console.log(modal, trigger);
      },
      onCloseEnd: function() { // Callback for Modal close
        alert('Closed');  
      } 
    }
  );
```

Comment: Well, this is very good, this functionality will be achieved in my next project in sha Allah. Thanks, @Syed.

Comment: How to do this without jquery?

Comment: $("#modal_id").modal('open', {
      dismissible: true,
      complete: function() { console.log('Close modal'); }
   })    for close and open put dismissible en false, that for materialize

Answer (score 2):

You can also get it after modal is Loaded by getting instance and update options like this :

```
const modal = M.Modal.getInstance(document.getElementById('your-modal-id'))
modal.options.onCloseEnd = () => {
   alert('closed')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm too late to share my thoughts here but in case you want to pass a variable/argument in your **function expression** when modal close. You may use this code

```
var onModalHide = function(param1) {
    alert("Modal closed!");
};

$("#id-of-your-modal").openModal({
    complete : onModalHide('your_parameter')
});
```

E.g. when you want to reset the fields of your form when modal close. Hope this will help. By the way, thanks to [Jack L](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1700390/jack-l)/@Jack L. (i dunno how to mention T.T)

Comment: This doesn't work because **adding parameters at the end of function executes it immidiately** and `undefined` is returned instead.

Comment: That's a valuable insight! And it's never too late :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case the `open` param was required to open the modal and detect `complete` event, example:

```
function openModal(){     
   $("#modal_id").modal('open', {
      dismissible: true,
      complete: function() { console.log('Close modal'); }
   })
}
```

Comment: $("#modal_id").modal('open', {
      dismissible: true,
      complete: function() { console.log('Close modal'); }
   })    for close and open put dismissible en false, that for materialize